# Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir

Tags: javascript, react-native, npm, npx, scandir

please I am running a react native project
but when I run the npx react-native run-android command, I get the error below

```
error EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir 'C:/Users/REO/AppData/Local/Application Data'.
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir 'C:/Users/REO/AppData/Local/Application Data'
    at Object.readdirSync (node:fs:1381:3)
    at GlobSync._readdir (C:\Users\REO\node_modules\glob\sync.js:285:46)
    at GlobSync._readdirInGlobStar (C:\Users\REO\node_modules\glob\sync.js:264:20)
    at GlobSync._readdir (C:\Users\REO\node_modules\glob\sync.js:273:17)
    at GlobSync._processReaddir (C:\Users\REO\node_modules\glob\sync.js:134:22)
    at GlobSync._process (C:\Users\REO\node_modules\glob\sync.js:129:10)
    at GlobSync._processGlobStar (C:\Users\REO\node_modules\glob\sync.js:377:10)
    at GlobSync._process (C:\Users\REO\node_modules\glob\sync.js:127:10)
    at GlobSync._processGlobStar (C:\Users\REO\node_modules\glob\sync.js:380:10)
    at GlobSync._process (C:\Users\REO\node_modules\glob\sync.js:127:10)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

Please can someone point out a solution..I've searched everywhere and haven't found a solution

Comment: It looks like you have put the React Native code you are trying to run directly in `C:\Users\REO`. (This is hinted at by the presence of `C:\Users\REO\node_modules` in your error.) Is this correct? If so, try creating a directory under `C:\Users\REO` (call it what you want but I suggest not including any spaces in its name), move your React Native code into this directory and try running it from this directory.

Comment: @LukeWoodward that's not the case...the project was in my desktop folder. I moved it to c:\Users\REO and it still gave me the issue

Comment: Moving your code *into* `C:\Users\REO` won't help here. I don't know if you've included the full output of your `npx react-native run-android` command, but it would help if you add the whole output to your question, unless it's excessively long.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with

```
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir 'C:\Config.Msi'
```

while trying to do an expo build using EAS.

Uninstalling and then reinstalling node fixed the issue for me.

https://nodejs.org/en/